# Indentation of the signature in the letter class

Tags: indentation, letters

I am writing a letter with the [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Letters) template.  The letter is going to be printed on a official paper which contains the address already. So I thought I can omit the `\address` command.  For some strange reason the signature will not indent as shown on the webpage. I tried the `\longindentation=20pt` command, no matter what numbers I change, the closing and the signature are all aligned to the left margin of the body and will not indent.  I was able to get it work by the command `\address{\phantom{a}}`, but that should not be how it is supposed to work (yes, I did try `\address{}`, but that doesn't work). Any better solutions?

What is wrong with omitting the `\address` command anyway?

Edit: Here is the what I am doing.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[11pt]{letter}

\signature{James Bond}
%\address{\phantom{i}}
%\longindentation=0pt
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}

\opening{To whom it may concern:}

The body of the letter goes on here. 

\closing{Yours sincerely,}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As it stands now, without the address command, the closing and signature will not indent. However, if we uncomment the `\address` command, then they indents as shown in the Wikibook LaTeX example.

Comment: Teh [UK TUG FAQ](http://www.math.uconn.edu/ITResources/Downloads/UkTeX371.pdf) correctly states that the `letter` class is widely disliked. It suggests `akletter`, `brief`, `dinbrief`, `newlfm`, and `scrlttr2` as alternatives.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason for the apparent "conditional indentation" stems from the source code for `\closing`:

```
\newcommand{\closing}[1]{\par\nobreak\vspace{\parskip}%
  \stopbreaks
  \noindent
  \ifx\@empty\fromaddress\else
  \hspace*{\longindentation}\fi
  \parbox{\indentedwidth}{\raggedright
       \ignorespaces #1\\[6\medskipamount]%
       \ifx\@empty\fromsig
           \fromname
       \else \fromsig \fi\strut}%
   \par}
```

The indent of `\longindentation` is only executed if `\fromaddress` is non-empty. And, `\fromaddress` is defined when using `\address`:

```
\newcommand*{\address}[1]{\def\fromaddress{#1}}
```

So, in order for the indentation to work properly (for whatever reason), you need something in `\fromaddress`. Using `\def\fromaddress{\null}` works just as well.

Answer (score 9):

you can also put

```
\longindentation=0pt
```

in the preamble (i.e. before `\begin{document})`.

Comment: It's better to give more details and, preferably, a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to verify that you have solved the OP. You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Answer (score 1):

You can patch it as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{letter}
%\address{\phantom{i}}
\signature{James Bond}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\closing}[1]{\par\nobreak\vspace{\parskip}%
 \stopbreaks
 \noindent
% \ifx\@empty\fromaddress\else
 \hspace*{\longindentation}
 \parbox{\indentedwidth}{\raggedright
 \ignorespaces #1\\[6\medskipamount]%
 \ifx\@empty\fromsig
 \fromname
 \else \fromsig \fi\strut}%
\par}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}

\opening{To whom it may concern:}

The body of the letter goes on here. 

\closing{Yours sincerely,}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```